# Tailwind won't work with sass, scss files

Tags: reactjs, sass, tailwind-css

I have tried installing tailwind to work in a react project, that also uses scss files. For whatever reason and have tried many solutions it just won't render in my browser any of the tailwind class names, nor apply any tailwind classes. They're not showing up in my element styles. Do I need to import anything to my tsx files etc? I just cannot for the life of me work it out.

My tailwind.config.js looks like:

```
    content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./src/pages/EntityPage/EntityPage.tsx"],
    important: true,
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
};
```

My postcss.config.js file looks like

```
export const plugins = [require("tailwindcss"), require("autoprefixer"), require("postcss-nested")];
```

and my index.css and App.scss both look like. I SHOULD add under the @tailwind there is a lien saying 'Unknown at rule @tailwindscss(unknownAtRules)' but from the looks of research elsewhere this is just a linting thing no?

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

body {
...
```

and lastly my entitypage.tsx looks like

```
return (
        <div className="entity-skeleton">
            <div className="w-full max-w-md px-2 py-16 sm:px-0">hi</div>
            <div className="w-full ma-w-md px-2 py-16 sm:px-0">
                <Tab.Group>
```

Is there anything I am missing?! It doesn't seem to be throwing up any errors anywhere! It just does not seem to work! Do I need to import anything in my entityPage? It seems to be fine as is!

Any help would be amazing!

Comment: insert the three `@tailwind` base, components, utilities in a separate file and then import it in your main `*.scss` file.

Comment: I added an tailwindUtil.scss file and imported those three as you said, and then imported them in to the app.scss file but unfortunately still nothing!

Comment: ohkay! did you read official docs of tailwindcss??

Comment: Unfortunately I did. followed them to the letter, i have tried importing in a number of different ways. As i say is throwing no errors which is to me baffling. I am just stumped

Comment: you can do one thing!! create a `global.css` and all `@tailwind` inside it and import it separately inside `App.js` and then create `app.scss` for styling then import the same.